# How to create an extension for Firebug

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firebug

I need to extend firebug to use the link extracted from the webpage(when a download from any link in the page is initiated) to send it to another machine where it will be downloaded. I was planning to use firebug to extract this link for me. If there is any other way I can get this information from the browser, even that would be appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for a custom type of Download Manager behaviour. I don't see what Firebug has to do with it.

Comment: You could _maybe_ use Firebug to help in the development of an extension, but this doesn't sound like something that would need to extend firebug. You would want to either make a full extension or use GreaseMonkey.

Comment: If not firebug, then is there a way to detect the link from where the download is initiated when a users clicks on a link to download.

Comment: You can use DOM APIs to attach listeners to relevant elements (or the document object) and look at the source of the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, its bad idea to use events to detect things like http requests,the power of firefox xul language gives you the ability to detect the all browsers requests/response then you can decide what links you need from the request/response header:
 
you can use "http-observe" witch actually Firebug use for the net panel
 
- here is the link for "http-observe" in mozilla MDN [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_HTTP_request_headers][1]
 
- also here is a simple example for "http-observe"

```
// first create observerService component as a property into your extension javascript object
    var myExtension = {   observerService:Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observerservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService),
        init:function(){
            // in the init function setup the observe service and set witch javascript object is the listener for http response for example "this"
            this.observerService.addObserver(this,"http-on-examine-response", false);
            this.observerService.addObserver(this,"http-on-examine-cached-response", false);
        },
        observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData){ // the observe function
            if (aTopic == "http-on-examine-response" || aTopic == "http-on-examine-cached-response"){
                var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
                var URI = httpChannel.originalURI.spec;                    
                if (aSubject.loadFlags & httpChannel.LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI){ // this detect if the response is primery request 
                    var contentType = httpChannel.getResponseHeader("content-type"); // check the heder content-type 
                    if (contentType == "what ever you want"){ // you can check if it zip/html/xml ...etc
                //do what ever you want
                }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo in above answer observer service call should read: `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);`

Reference for Observer Service usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIObserverService